# How to select start layout with Bottom Navigation Bar?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I want to select the start layout in my project.
For example after: After user successfully sign-in I want to see redirect him to `fragment_home` page but now he is redirected to friends layout. **Please help**.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
        //it might be working but it isn't 
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.nav_home:
                            selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_ranking:
                            selectedFragment = new RankingFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_friends:
                            selectedFragment = new FriendsFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_game:
                            selectedFragment = new GameFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_user:
                            selectedFragment = new UserFragment();
                            break;
                    }

                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            selectedFragment).commit();

                    return true;
                }
            };
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoS4o.png <<< photo
Here is my menu of BottomBar

> ```
> <item
>     android:id="@+id/nav_game"
>     android:icon="@drawable/ic_game"
>     android:title="Game"/>
>
> <item
>     android:id="@+id/nav_home"
>     android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
>     android:title="Home"/>
>
> <item
>     android:id="@+id/nav_ranking"
>     android:icon="@drawable/ic_ranking"
>     android:title="Ranking"/>
>
> <item
>     android:id="@+id/nav_user"
>     android:icon="@drawable/ic_user"
>     android:title="User"/>
> ```

Comment: can you show your menu  ?

Comment: Have you thought about using a breakpoint and figure out why the item param is what it is?

Comment: Instead of loading the fragment with a transaction, try this: bottomNav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home);

Comment: Re:Have you thought about using a breakpoint (..) I don't work :(

Comment: Re:Have you thought about using a breakpoint and figure out why the item param is what it is? Thanks a lot <3 it's working !!!